# What can be done about a WIndows Phone 10 lock screen hanging

Tags: windows-10-mobile, lock-screen

This may have started happening after I allowed the Weatherbug app to be a part of my Lumia 950 XL lock screen. That is no longer the case, but I am repeatedly getting a situation where - after the screen locks - I can't unlock it. The keypad to enter my pin will not display and I have to reboot to get use of the phone.

I can swipe down from the top and see the settings panel and I can swipe up to get rid of the time and my Outlook mail status, it's just that the keypad to unlock the phone will not display.

Comment: Hard reset should help. If it doesn't help try with reseting your phone with PC. Here you can find more about windows recovery tool. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12379/windows-10-mobile-device-recovery-tool-faq

Comment: This was a bug in early builds of W10M. Try updating on the latest build which hopefully will resolve your problem.